# I had a larger sized webp file from any image file(jpg, png, etc) in JavaCV(OpenCV)

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

This is a **java code** that translate a image to **a webp image** in **JavaCV(OpenCV)**.
I could rum this code and get a output webp image.
But the file size was larger than the original image file.
Is there anything else I should do?
For your information, I could reduce the file size if I use the [**webp-imageio**](https://github.com/sejda-pdf/webp-imageio).
Thank you.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  trans image
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private void transImage() throws IOException {

    //load library
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    //root path
    String pathRoot = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    //file path
    String pathFileFrom = pathRoot + "/src/sample.jpg";
    String pathFileTo   = pathRoot + "/src/sampleOut.webp";

    //extension
    String extension    = ".webp";

    //matrix
    Mat matFrom = new Mat();
    Mat matTo   = new Mat();

    //read image
    matFrom = Imgcodecs.imread(pathFileFrom);

    //byte matrix
    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();

    //encode image
    boolean blEncode = Imgcodecs.imencode(extension, matFrom, matOfByte);

    //decode image
    matTo = Imgcodecs.imdecode(matOfByte, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);

    //save
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(pathFileTo, matTo);
}
```

Comment: It's not a very good idea to convert an already compressed image to a webp. Try converting a raw to a jpeg and webp and compare their size and quality differences instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This is my first time using it, so I didn't know how to use it well..

Comment: It's more about image processing theory. You can't reliably uncompress a lossy compressed image like jpeg, recompress it with a different codec and expect good things to happen.

Comment: what is this? imread, imencode, imdecode, imwrite? that's pointless steps. what do you really care about?

Comment: I'm a beginner but I understood what you want to say. Jpeg is a lossy compressed image. Png and tiff are a compressed image. So I can recompress the latter images. I just want to reduce the image file size.

Comment: You could reduce the quality by setting the IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY parameter: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42aca7d3f848cc45d3138de0a2053d213a54a

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong.

**Imgcodecs** is **the OpenCV class** and **opencv_imgcodecs** is **the JavaCV class**.

So I should use the JavaCV class and shold not use the OpenCV one.

In addition, the both should not be mixed.

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv